# ie8 css visibility - fixed div or ul

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, visibility

My problem is that although the site seems to work fine in Chrome, in version of IE8 the fixed bar(div and ul) is invisible. I have tested with X-UA-COMPATIBLE option, IF IE conditional sentence, but I can not solve it at all. I have struggled about 1 week, now I am so tired.
And in IE9, it is much slower than that of chrome.

My site address is http://kyuh.maddesign.co.kr

I do apologize if there is a obvious and simple answer that I've been too stupid to spot.

Comment: You have a [whole bunch of invalid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkyuh.maddesign.co.kr%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  No wonder IE is not working correctly... it chokes on invalid HTML.  Fix the HTML and then troubleshoot what's left.

Comment: It would also help if you weren't hiding some elements in Firefox and not in IE. It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

At last, this problem is fixed. 
For a long time of googling and many tries, I have found what is working in my case. 
It is.... {zoom: 1} css option.

```
.ie8 classname {zoom: 1}
```

If you have same problem, try this one!